# Append .git to string read using readarray

Tags: bash

I'm writting a script in Bash. In it I read a long list of names using readarray. I want to create another array with the names of the first array concatenated with ".git". That is, I have a file like this:

```
first
second
third
```

and want to have an array with data

```
first.git
second.git
third.git
```

but I get:

```
.gitt
.gitnd
third.git
```

Yes, the last one always work. If I don't use readarray but a local variable like this:

```
files=("first" "second" "third")
```

everything works. This is the minimal script that reproduces the issue:

```
readarray repo_names < repoNames.txt 

for it in ${repo_names[@]}; do
  echo "${it}.git"
done

test=("first" "second" "third")
for it in ${test[@]}; do
  echo "${it}.git"
done
```

result:

```
user@debian:~/git/code/transfer$ ./tmp2.sh 
.gitt
.gitnd
third.git
first.git
second.git
third.git
```

Why is it appending the string, overwritting it, instead of concatenating?

Comment: That was it! it had windows line endings. if you write that as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one

Comment: You do not even need a loop: `files=("first" "second" "third"); printf '%s.git\n' "${files[@]}"`

Comment: Or `files=( "${files[@]/%/.git}" )` to update all the array entries at once with a [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).